# sudo git diff <filename> using MELD.app does not show the ancestor version (OSX)

Tags: git, macos

[OSX C-ERROR 10.12]

I finally got `sudo git diff <filename>` to open MELD.
My wrapper script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
open /Applications/Meld.app --args $2 $5
```

When MELD opens up, the right panel has the file whose name I typed `$5`, but the left panel, where the ancestor `$2` of `<filename>` should be displayed, is empty.  MELD's title bar tells me the filename of the ancestor has a random prefix pre-pended.  By echoing `$2` in my script before Meld runs, I can see that the file is located in `/tmp/`, however there is no such file in `/tmp/` and I assume that is why the left panel is blank.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

*As an aside, I don't understand why I need to use `sudo` to make this work!  Without `sudo` it doesn't work in-spite of setting ownerships and permissions on the wrapper script file and the folder its in to to root/wheel & 777.  Any clarification would be appreciated.*

Comment: I don't know why you need a `sudo` but I have run into the other part of the problem: temp files that Git creates, Git removes as soon as the wrapper exits. So `open /...` spins off an RPC request, which succeeds (the RPC request that is), and `open` then exits successfully, and Git removes the temp file, and finally the app acts on the RPC ... by which time, the file is gone.  There is no perfect solution in general, but in a lot of cases you can sleaze it easily with a short `sleep`. Ideally, you wait for the app to tell you "I am done with this file" but many apps never tell you anything.

Comment: Thanks torek, where would I put the sleep and how would it be implemented, using `&&`?

Comment: Just add `sleep 0.2` after the `open` command (next line). Adjust 0.2 (it's in seconds) up or down as needed/desired. Should be safe to let the thing wait for many seconds, since your Meld.app is running quite independently of this: if you said `sleep 3600` (1 hour) that would give you an hour to work in Meld before the temp file gets removed. If you're finished in Meld in 10 minutes, the diff will wait the remaining 50 minutes: this is the only pressure to keep it short. As long as Meld doesn't get upset if the underlying file goes away, there's no pressure to make it long.

Comment: Well, that helped diagnosing some of the problems.  It gave me time to see that the file is actually being created, but with the owner/permissions set to `root:wheel 400` (Since I need to use `sudo`.)
But, Meld is being run using my account, so it is not able to open it.  To fix this, I changed my wrapper script to point directly to the executable inside the APP:  `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/MacOS/Meld $2 $5` and now it works when I use `sudo`.

Comment: What will be nice is to figure out why I need to use `sudo`.  I added Meld to my Accessibility list in the System Security Preferences, but that didn't help.

Comment: What about folder permissions?  I've tried three different ways now: wrapper in /usr/local/bin, wrapper in ~/git, and wrapper in ~/git with symlink from /usr/local/bin to it.

Comment: The reason for the need to use `sudo` is because I had `export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=$HOME/git` in my profile and it was conflicting with what I had in my `.gitconfig`.  At some point I set it thinking it would work in conjunction to what I had in the config file.

Comment: Interesting. Git generally has env variables override, so that must have made it just recursively invoke `$HOME/git`.